# NPM Install --global "package" VS NPM Install -g "package"?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, global

Can anyone tell me what the difference is?

```
NPM Install -g "package"
```

**VS**

```
NPM Install --global "package"
```

Comment: There is no difference. They both are the same. From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), `In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.`

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured..pretty simple question, I know. Just couldn't find anything on the Google :)

Answer (score 2):

They are the same thing with no added benefit of one over the other; `--global` I think is newer, but I could be wrong with that statement.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought..just wasn't sure.